# La opacidad del div afecta el texto que se encuentra en otro div superior a el

Tags: html, css, aplicación-web, div

Basicamente, tengo un div que posee texto, y otro div que solo es utilizado para generar un cuadro de color negro que este sobre el texto, pero este posee una menor opacidad, para que el fondo del body sea visible. La opacidad del div-cuadro es de 0.2, pero el mismo afecta el color del div-texto, por lo que si yo lo asigne con color blanco, este texto se vera un poco mas oscuro.
A simple vista, pareciera que el div-fondo esta arriba del div-texto, por lo que si yo pongo su opacidad normal, este tapara completamente el texto.

CODIGO HTML:

```
    <div id="contenedor1">
    <div id="cont-titulo">
    <h2>Titulo de presentacion</h2>
    <div id="cont-subtitulo">
    <p id="frase-subtit"></p>
    <p id="date">Aqui deberia de verse la hora actual :)</p>
    </div>
    </div>
            
    <nav>
    <ul class="navegacion">
    <li><a href="#">Sitio A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sitio B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sitio C</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sitio D</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>

    <section>
    <article>
    <p>Bienvenido! Seleccione la zona de trabajo en la <b>fila de navegacion</b> que esta arriba de este texto</p>

    </article>
    </section>

    <aside id="cont-aside">
    <h4>Sitios de utilidad: </h4>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="f">Sitio 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="f">Sitio 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="f">Sitio 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="f">Sitio 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="f">Sitio 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="f">Sitio 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="f">Sitio 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="f">Sitio 8</a></li>
    </ul>
    </aside>
    </div>  
        
    <div id="fondo-text"></div>
```

CODIGO CSS:

```
    * {
    color: white; 
    opacity: 1.0;}

    body {
    background-color: grey; }

    #contenedor1 {    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 55%;
    padding: 25px; 
    }

    #fondo-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.2;
    width: 55%;
    padding: 25px;
    }
```

AQUI HAY UN EJEMPLO DE COMO QUIERO QUE SE VEA (TOMANDO LOS TEXTOS Y EL FONDO):
https://undertale.fandom.com/es/wiki/Toriel
https://darksouls.fandom.com/es/wiki/Wiki_Dark_Souls

Comment: Voy a echarle un vistazo a tu código. Si quieres, agrégame a Discord y lo solucionamos por ahí: ortiz#6026

Comment: Puedes agregar z-index:1; a tu elemento de id contenedor 1 para que se posicione sobre el que quieres que esté entre el fondo y el elemento. #contenedor1 {    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 55%;
    padding: 25px; 
    z-index: 1;
    }

Comment: Declara el div de fondo antes del div de texto.

Comment: Gracias a los 3, especialmente a Sal, ya lo logre!!